# Reading symbols from sshell...(no debugging symbols found)...done. (Yes, I used -g when compiling)

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, makefile, gdb

For some reason I am getting this 
error message and won't allow me to step through my code.

```
ubuntu (master *) ECS150-Simple-Shell $ gdb sshell
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.04) 7.11.1
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from sshell...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) b LoadTerminal
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4010e8
(gdb) r
Starting program: /media/ubuntu/folder/sshell 
warning: the debug information found in "/lib64/ld-2.23.so" does not match "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" (CRC mismatch).


Breakpoint 1, 0x00000000004010e8 in LoadTerminal ()
(gdb) n
Single stepping until exit from function LoadTerminal,
which has no line number information.
sshell$
```

Instead of stepping through line by line, it stepped through the end of the code.

My Makefile

```
objects = main.o terminal.o history.o parser.o 
cc = gcc
cflags = -g -Werror
sshell: $(objects)
    $(cc) $(cflags) $(objects) -o sshell
    rm $(objects)
main.o: main.c
terminal.o: terminal.c
history.o: history.c
parser.o: parser.c
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm sshell
```

My Makefile with -g on every object file

```
objects = main.o terminal.o history.o parser.o 
cc = gcc
cflags = -g -Werror
sshell: $(objects)
    $(cc) $(cflags) $(objects) -o sshell
    rm $(objects)
main.o: main.c
gcc -g -Werror -c main.c -o main.o
terminal.o: terminal.c
gcc -g -Werror -c terminal.c -o terminal.o
history.o: history.c
gcc -g -Werror -c history.c -o history.o
parser.o: parser.c
gcc -g -Werror -c parser.c -o parser.o
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm sshell
```

I have even tried adding the -g options to my object files, but I get the same error.

Comment: You absolutely have to use `-g` when compiling the `.c` files.  From your Makefile fragment there's no indication that this is happening.  You can verify whether `sshell` has debug info via `readelf -WS sshell | grep debug`.

Answer (score 0):

> For some reason

There are a few possible reasons. The most likely reason that I could guess is that your `gcc` isn't really a `/usr/bin/gcc`, but some shell wrapper, which passes different flags to `/usr/bin/gcc`.

Another possible reason is that you are debugging the wrong binary. GDB says you are debugging `/media/ubuntu/folder/sshell`, but is that the binary that you build?

> My `Makefile`.

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your `Makefile` (besides using unconventional variables for `CC`, `CLFAGS`, etc. -- `make` is case-sensitive).

Instead of showing the `Makefile`, you really should snow the *command* that `make clean sshell` produces.

Here are the steps I would use to triage this problem:

1. Verify that the compile and final link commands actually contain `-g`
2. Verify that `gcc` is `/usr/bin/gcc`
3. Verify that `/media/ubuntu/folder/sshell` has been modified at expected time (with `ls -l`).
4. Verify that it contains debug info: `readelf -WS /media/ubuntu/folder/sshell | grep '\.debug'`

At least one of the above statements likely false. If they are all true, you have a broken GCC or binutils installation.

Comment: I haven't specified a rule for 'all' in my Makefile. But make clean produces the output: rm sshell. No errors.

And what do you mean debugging the wrong binary? sshell is the executable that I compiled with the -g flag. 

And #4, sshell does not contain the debug info. Why?